# How to avoid Dupliate value in View

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a ProductList with Product of different categorises.
I dont want my  view to hold duplicate values.

[image: screenshot product list]

ProductController.cs

public ActionResult ProductList()
        {

```
        IEnumerable<ProductListDTO> ProductList;
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            ProductList = from a in _db.ProductMsts
                              join b in _db.ProductTypeMsts on a.fk_prodtypeid equals b.pk_prodtypeid
                              select new ProductListDTO
                              {
                                  pk_ProductId = a.pk_ProductId,
                                  ProductType = b.Description,
                                  ProductName = a.ProductName,
                                  OriginalPrice = a.OriginalPrice,
                                  ProductQuantity = a.ProductQuantity,
                                  SellingUptoPrice = a.SellingUptoPrice
                              };

        }
        else
        {
             ProductList = from a in _db.ProductMsts
                              join b in _db.ProductTypeMsts on a.fk_prodtypeid equals b.pk_prodtypeid
                           where a.username==User.Identity.Name

                              select new ProductListDTO
                              {
                                  pk_ProductId = a.pk_ProductId,
                                  ProductType = b.Description,
                                  ProductName = a.ProductName,
                                  OriginalPrice = a.OriginalPrice,
                                  ProductQuantity = a.ProductQuantity,
                                  SellingUptoPrice = a.SellingUptoPrice
                              };
        }

        return View(ProductList);
```

Comment: you can use `Distinct` method of clause

Comment: like `return View(ProductList.Distinct());`

Comment: return View(ProductList.Distinct());   But in the View It is still showing same product double time

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected output as `text`? which may more helpful to understand your problem

Comment: I have given product_Type : Mobile ProductName: Samsung OriPrice : 12000 SellingPrice : 15000 quantity: 200 expected output is that if i insert duplicate record that reocrd shouldnot be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` with the query syntax you have used.

```
ProductList = from a in _db.ProductMsts
                              join b in _db.ProductTypeMsts on a.fk_prodtypeid equals b.pk_prodtypeid
                              select new ProductListDTO
                              {
                                  pk_ProductId = a.pk_ProductId,
                                  ProductType = b.Description,
                                  ProductName = a.ProductName,
                                  OriginalPrice = a.OriginalPrice,
                                  ProductQuantity = a.ProductQuantity,
                                  SellingUptoPrice = a.SellingUptoPrice
                              }.Distinct();
```